# Wired connection icon is displayed instead of Wifi icon - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, 16.04, network-manager, indicator

I am connected to a WiFi network but wired connection icon is shown:

Screen-shot of the problem:

[image]

I also can't see other available WiFi networks in order to connect to them.

Output for `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`:

```
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

What should I do?

Comment: +1 very strange indeed. And I also notice it doesn't show you the list of SSIDs...

Comment: Also when I disable then re-enable wifi, it shows the wifi icon trying to connect to the saved network. But when it's connected, wired network connection is shown.

Comment: What WiFi hardware do you have ? You can check with `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`.

Comment: @JonasCz: I added the output to the question.

Comment: Do you have the Broadcom drivers enabled in the "Additional drivers" utility ?

Comment: Yes, they are enabled.

Comment: @arman_aegit Could you add output of `ifconfig -a` , `more /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces.d/* /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/* /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

Comment: Bug persists in ubuntu 16.10. After suspend, network manager thinks I'm connected via wire. However, if I go to system-settings -> network I can see the list of nearby SSIDs and confirm the fact that I'm connected to the correct network.

Comment: This issue persists for me in 16.04 after a suspend... I was just getting comfortable using suspend again, and now I'm hesitant; this kind of quirky behavior is what turned me off to suspend years ago -- in fact, I almost always encounter issues when I use suspend or hibernate on Windows, so I prohibit its use on those system where I'm concerned.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is caused by a [bug in Network Manager](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1576726).  It seems that when wlan0 is renamed using the [new naming scheme](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) it confuses Network Manager and Network Manager thinks you have another ethernet connection.

It can normally be fixed with

```
systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

The command will have to be done after a reboot or suspend until the fixes are released

Comment: Is it possible by changing the interface name?

Comment: And it looks like the bug has been fixed. Probably the system needs to be updated.

Comment: It looks like `b43` should be used with this adapter insted of `wl`.

Comment: Pilot6: No, I just updated, the problem persists.

Comment: Any word on if this bug has been fixed yet?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my WiFi driver to rtlwifi_new, and it seems to have solved the issue. I get the normal WiFi icon when I suspend my computer now. Thank goodness!

Comment: What OS are you using @UnityLauncherProblems ? I'm curious about using this driver, but would be hesitant unless I knew more about it. I found it on GitHub (https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new), but otherwise am not sure about its use...

Comment: can you add the steps of changing the wifi driver please?