# Ubuntu 16.04 with proprietary wifi driver won't stay suspended

Tags: drivers, 16.04, suspend

After doing an in place dist-upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04, I chose to replace the kernel wifi driver with the vendor proprietary to enhance signal and throughput. The driver install named the device  enp3s0f0 (in a very Solaris-like manner)

Since then, when I go into suspend mode my machine immediately unsuspends.

Logs follow, but I think the most interesting bit is from powersave.log:

```
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless false:
Turning powersave for enp3s0f0 off...Error for wireless request "Set Power Management" (8B2C) :
    SET failed on device enp3s0f0 ; Operation not supported.
Failed.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless false: success.
```

But I don't know how to proceed from there.

Dmesg from suspend:

```
[ 2891.587542] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[ 2891.786445] PM: Preparing system for sleep (mem)
[ 2891.786612] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
[ 2891.788869] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[ 2891.790251] PM: Suspending system (mem)
[ 2891.790270] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[ 2891.792330] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 2891.813004] CacheVal-OnOff:0, bPCIclkOff:1, WlanFunCtrl:0xff000533
[ 2891.813007] ==> RTMPWlan 0, bPCIclkOff = 1, pAd->WlanFunCtrl.word = 0xff000523
[ 2891.813007] Set INT_MASK_CSR = 0
[ 2891.813014] ==> RTMPWlan 0, bPCIclkOff = 1, WlanFunCtrl.word = 0xff000520
[ 2891.813017] <== RTMPWlan 0  bPCIclkOff = 1 pAd->WlanFunCtrl.word = 0xff000520
[ 2891.820060] CacheVal-OnOff:0, bPCIclkOff:1, WlanFunCtrl:0xff000520
[ 2891.820068] ==> RTMPWlan 0, bPCIclkOff = 1, pAd->WlanFunCtrl.word = 0xff000520
[ 2891.820069] Set INT_MASK_CSR = 0
[ 2891.820098] ==> RTMPWlan 0, bPCIclkOff = 1, WlanFunCtrl.word = 0xff000520
[ 2891.820101] <== RTMPWlan 0  bPCIclkOff = 1 pAd->WlanFunCtrl.word = 0xff000520
[ 2891.821127] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[ 2892.519637] PM: suspend of devices complete after 729.169 msecs
[ 2892.535639] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 15.997 msecs
[ 2892.536331] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[ 2892.536353] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[ 2892.536575] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[ 2892.536752] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[ 2892.551722] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 16.079 msecs
[ 2892.552150] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[ 2892.552446] ACPI : EC: EC stopped
[ 2892.552447] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[ 2892.552454] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[ 2892.552766] Broke affinity for irq 16
[ 2892.552769] Broke affinity for irq 23
[ 2892.552776] Broke affinity for irq 28
[ 2892.553807] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[ 2892.564254] Broke affinity for irq 16
[ 2892.564257] Broke affinity for irq 23
[ 2892.564261] Broke affinity for irq 26
[ 2892.564263] Broke affinity for irq 27
[ 2892.564265] Broke affinity for irq 28
[ 2892.564268] Broke affinity for irq 30
[ 2892.564275] Broke affinity for irq 34
[ 2892.565297] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[ 2892.576148] Broke affinity for irq 1
[ 2892.576151] Broke affinity for irq 8
[ 2892.576152] Broke affinity for irq 9
[ 2892.576156] Broke affinity for irq 16
[ 2892.576158] Broke affinity for irq 23
[ 2892.576161] Broke affinity for irq 26
[ 2892.576163] Broke affinity for irq 27
[ 2892.576165] Broke affinity for irq 28
[ 2892.576166] Broke affinity for irq 29
[ 2892.576168] Broke affinity for irq 30
[ 2892.576172] Broke affinity for irq 33
[ 2892.576175] Broke affinity for irq 34
[ 2892.577200] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[ 2892.593057] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[ 2892.593097] ACPI : EC: EC started
[ 2892.593097] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[ 2892.594053] microcode: CPU0 microcode updated early to revision 0x1c, date = 2015-02-26
[ 2892.594081] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[ 2892.613111] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[ 2892.613112] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[ 2892.613666] microcode: CPU1 microcode updated early to revision 0x1c, date = 2015-02-26
[ 2892.616204]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
[ 2892.616304] CPU1 is up
[ 2892.633160] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
[ 2892.633737] microcode: CPU2 microcode updated early to revision 0x1c, date = 2015-02-26
[ 2892.636330]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
[ 2892.636436] CPU2 is up
[ 2892.653163] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
[ 2892.653720] microcode: CPU3 microcode updated early to revision 0x1c, date = 2015-02-26
[ 2892.656309]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
[ 2892.656407] CPU3 is up
[ 2892.659195] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[ 2892.673188] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 2892.673392] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 2892.673669] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 2892.673734] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 14.271 msecs
[ 2892.674051] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.289 msecs
[ 2892.678501] rtc_cmos 00:02: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 2892.679458] MACVersion=0x32900015
[ 2892.679459] CacheVal-OnOff:1, bPCIclkOff:0, WlanFunCtrl:0xff000520
[ 2892.679466] ==> RTMPWlan 1, bPCIclkOff = 0, pAd->WlanFunCtrl.word = 0xff000522
[ 2892.679467] ==> RTMPWlan 1, bPCIclkOff = 0, WlanFunCtrl.word = 0xff000521
[ 2892.679474] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 2892.679603] <== RTMPWlan 1  bPCIclkOff = 0 pAd->WlanFunCtrl.word = 0xff000523
[ 2892.679616] PllCtrl:0x26c5555
[ 2892.680954] RX DESC ffff88003e2a2000  size = 2048
[ 2892.681138] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900019eed60!
[ 2892.681139] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900019eedd0!
[ 2892.681139] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900019eee40!
[ 2892.681140] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900019eecf0!
[ 2892.681141] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900019eeba0!
[ 2892.681141] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900019eec10!
[ 2892.681142] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900019b8d20!
[ 2892.681142] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900019b8d90!
[ 2892.681143] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900019b8c38!
[ 2892.681143] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900019a7b30!
[ 2892.681144] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900019a7ba8!
[ 2892.681145] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900019b8b58!
[ 2892.681146] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900019b8e20!
[ 2892.683205] BBP_R105: BBPR105.field.EnableSIGRemodulation = 1, BBPR105.field.MLDFor2Stream = 0
[ 2892.684243] no file read method
[ 2892.684244] Read file "/etc/Wireless/RT2860STA/RT2860STA.dat" failed(errCode=-1)!
[ 2892.684245] 1. Phy Mode = 0
[ 2892.684246] 2. Phy Mode = 0
[ 2892.684251] NVM is Efuse and its size =1e[1e0-1fd] 
[ 2892.685786] 3. Phy Mode = 0
[ 2892.686098] AntCfgInit: primary/secondary ant 0/1

[ 2892.686098] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[ 2892.741871] CacheVal-OnOff:1, bPCIclkOff:0, WlanFunCtrl:0xff000523
[ 2892.741875] ==> RTMPWlan 1, bPCIclkOff = 0, pAd->WlanFunCtrl.word = 0xff000533
[ 2892.741875] <== RTMPWlan bPCIclkOff = 0, Exit because WLAN EN is already ON 
[ 2892.744983] MCS Set = 00 00 00 00 00
[ 2892.744988] <==== rt28xx_init, Status=0
[ 2892.745044] 0x1300 = 00073200
[ 2892.745044] RTMPrt3xSetPCIePowerLinkCtrl.===> 1e
[ 2893.005023] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[ 2893.006844] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)
[ 2893.006850] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT1._GTF] (Node ffff8802170bad98), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
[ 2893.009086] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)
[ 2893.009092] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT1._GTF] (Node ffff8802170bad98), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
[ 2893.009100] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 2893.013025] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[ 2893.013047] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
[ 2893.013336] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)
[ 2893.013341] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff8802170bad20), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
[ 2893.014011] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)
[ 2893.014017] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff8802170bad20), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
[ 2893.014289] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 2893.025035] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
[ 2893.170950] PM: resume of devices complete after 496.880 msecs
[ 2893.171220] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[ 2893.171221] Restarting tasks ... 
[ 2893.171465] pci_bus 0000:01: Allocating resources
[ 2893.171490] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 01] add_size 1000
[ 2893.171496] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 01] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
```

...
    [ 2893.171895] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: BAR 13: assigned [io  0x6000-0x6fff]
    [ 2893.178506] done.
    [ 2893.178687] video LNXVIDEO:01: Restoring backlight state
    [ 2894.331856] ===>rt_ioctl_giwscan. 20(20) BSS returned, data->length = 4392
    [ 2894.351273] SSDA:(Two) Antenna Configuration
    [ 2894.351286] cmbCtrl = 50c0f6c4

pm-suspend.log:

```
Initial commandline parameters: 
Sat Aug 13 09:59:38 EDT 2016: Running hooks for suspend.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend:
Linux office-desktop 4.4.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 27 16:06:39 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Module                  Size  Used by
xt_CHECKSUM            16384  1
```

...
    rt3290sta            1155072  1
    rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
...
    fjes                   28672  0
                  total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
    Mem:        8035784     2294164     3213996      302072     2527624     5085620
    Swap:       8447996           0     8447996
    /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend: success.

```
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/40inputattach suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/40inputattach suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant suspend suspend:
Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend:
Kernel modesetting video driver detected, not using quirks.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend:
kernel.acpi_video_flags = 0
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend suspend suspend: success.

Sat Aug 13 09:59:39 EDT 2016: performing suspend
Sat Aug 13 09:59:44 EDT 2016: Awake.
Sat Aug 13 09:59:44 EDT 2016: Running hooks for resume
Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend resume suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led resume suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm resume suspend:

/dev/sda:
 setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
 APM_level  = 254
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock resume suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules resume suspend:
Reloaded unloaded modules.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant resume suspend:
Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/40inputattach resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/40inputattach resume suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate resume suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate resume suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common resume suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend: success.

Sat Aug 13 09:59:44 EDT 2016: Finished.
```

pm-powersave.log

```
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/95hdparm-apm false:

/dev/sda:
 setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
 APM_level  = 254
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/95hdparm-apm false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/anacron false:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/anacron false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/disable_wol false:
Setting Wake On Lan for eth0 to enable...Done.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/disable_wol false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/intel-audio-powersave false:
Setting power savings for snd_hda_intel to 0...Done.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/intel-audio-powersave false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/laptop-mode false:
Laptop mode disabled.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/laptop-mode false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pci_devices false:
Setting Host Bridge 0000:00:00.0 to on
Setting Audio device 0000:00:1b.0 to on
Setting Wireless device 0000:03:00.0 to on
Setting Ethernet device 0000:06:00.0 to on
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pci_devices false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pcie_aspm false:
sh: echo: I/O error
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pcie_aspm false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/sata_alpm false:
Setting SATA ALPM on host0 to max_performance...Done.
Setting SATA ALPM on host1 to max_performance...Done.
Setting SATA ALPM on host2 to max_performance...Done.
Setting SATA ALPM on host3 to max_performance...Done.
Setting SATA ALPM on host4 to max_performance...Done.
Setting SATA ALPM on host5 to max_performance...Done.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/sata_alpm false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/sched-powersave false:
**sched policy powersave OFF
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/sched-powersave false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/usb_bluetooth false:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/usb_bluetooth false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless false:
Turning powersave for wlan0 off...Done.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/xfs_buffer false:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/xfs_buffer false: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/95hdparm-apm false:

/dev/sda:
 setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
 APM_level  = 254
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/95hdparm-apm false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/anacron false:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/anacron false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/disable_wol false:
Setting Wake On Lan for eth0 to enable...Done.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/disable_wol false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/intel-audio-powersave false:
Setting power savings for snd_hda_intel to 0...Done.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/intel-audio-powersave false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/laptop-mode false:
Laptop mode disabled.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/laptop-mode false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pci_devices false:
Setting Host Bridge 0000:00:00.0 to on
Setting Audio device 0000:00:1b.0 to on
Setting Wireless device 0000:03:00.0 to on
Setting Ethernet device 0000:06:00.0 to on
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pci_devices false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pcie_aspm false:
sh: echo: I/O error
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pcie_aspm false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/sata_alpm false:
Setting SATA ALPM on host0 to max_performance...Done.
Setting SATA ALPM on host1 to max_performance...Done.
Setting SATA ALPM on host2 to max_performance...Done.
Setting SATA ALPM on host3 to max_performance...Done.
Setting SATA ALPM on host4 to max_performance...Done.
Setting SATA ALPM on host5 to max_performance...Done.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/sata_alpm false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/sched-powersave false:
**sched policy powersave OFF
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/sched-powersave false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/usb_bluetooth false:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/usb_bluetooth false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless false:
Turning powersave for enp3s0f0 off...Error for wireless request "Set Power Management" (8B2C) :
    SET failed on device enp3s0f0 ; Operation not supported.
Failed.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/xfs_buffer false:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/xfs_buffer false: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/95hdparm-apm false:

/dev/sda:
 setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
 APM_level  = 254
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/95hdparm-apm false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/anacron false:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/anacron false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/disable_wol false:
Setting Wake On Lan for eth0 to enable...Done.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/disable_wol false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/intel-audio-powersave false:
Setting power savings for snd_hda_intel to 0...Done.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/intel-audio-powersave false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/laptop-mode false:
Laptop mode disabled.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/laptop-mode false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pci_devices false:
Setting Host Bridge 0000:00:00.0 to on
Setting Audio device 0000:00:1b.0 to on
Setting Wireless device 0000:03:00.0 to on
Setting Ethernet device 0000:06:00.0 to on
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pci_devices false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pcie_aspm false:
sh: echo: I/O error
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pcie_aspm false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/sata_alpm false:
Setting SATA ALPM on host0 to max_performance...Done.
Setting SATA ALPM on host1 to max_performance...Done.
Setting SATA ALPM on host2 to max_performance...Done.
Setting SATA ALPM on host3 to max_performance...Done.
Setting SATA ALPM on host4 to max_performance...Done.
Setting SATA ALPM on host5 to max_performance...Done.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/sata_alpm false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/sched-powersave false:
**sched policy powersave OFF
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/sched-powersave false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/usb_bluetooth false:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/usb_bluetooth false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless false:
Turning powersave for enp3s0f0 off...Error for wireless request "Set Power Management" (8B2C) :
    SET failed on device enp3s0f0 ; Operation not supported.
Failed.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/xfs_buffer false:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/xfs_buffer false: not applicable.



The salient part of the powersave logs appears to be:
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless false:
Turning powersave for enp3s0f0 off...Error for wireless request "Set Power Management" (8B2C) :
    SET failed on device enp3s0f0 ; Operation not supported.
Failed.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless false: success.
```

iwconfig:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

virbr0-nic  no wireless extensions.

enp3s0f0  Ralink STA  ESSID:"Casablanca"  Nickname:"RT3290STA"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.437 GHz  Access Point: 00:26:EC:01:D4:9D   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   
          RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Link Quality=70/100  Signal level:-71 dBm  Noise level:-93 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: "Turning powersave for enp3s0f0 off...Error for wireless request "Set Power Management" (8B2C) :
    SET failed on device enp3s0f0 ; Operation not supported." I suspect that enp3s0f0 is an ethernet interface, not wireless. May we also see: `iwconfig`?

Comment: I added it above. I can manipulate it via iwconfig (up/down it, bind to SSID, etc.)

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/789843/wired-connection-icon-is-displayed-instead-of-wifi-icon-ubuntu-16-04 Does it change at all if you do: `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service` ?

Comment: It did not. Network manager was having issues seeing the interface so I disabled it and installed wicd. If having NetMan helps I will convert back.