# Wifi logo changes to ethernet

Tags: madwifi

I have a SP3 with ubuntu 16.04 in it.. I have updated to the latest kernel available 
Because my device used to freeze if I suspened it and I had to hard reset it.. Now it's working very good after updating the kernel but now there is something wrong with the wifi.. the logo changes to ethernet and sometimes it disconnects by itself.. how to fix this problem

Comment: I think this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789843/wired-connection-icon-is-displayed-instead-of-wifi-icon-ubuntu-16-04) is the answer to your problem.

Comment: Thanks that helps.. but I have to do it everytime I open my device after suspend.. isn't there any better solution?